# Swype installed but does nothing

Tags: keyboard, swype

I downloaded and installed swype on my HTC Droid incredible 2. I went to settings > keyboard > text settings and checked swype. Now when I use my keyboard I draw across the letters and nothing happens.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to switch to Swype from the default keyboard?

Press and hold inside any text box (like Google Search, for example).  A pop-up should come up with one or more options.  Select the "Input method" option and then select "Swype".